# How multiply and sum two columns with group by in django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, group-by

I need to do the following query in Django:

```
SELECT sum(T.width * T.height) as amount
FROM triangle T
WHERE T.type = 'normal'
GROUP BY S.color
```

How can I do this using your django ORM?
I tried this:

```
Triangle.objects.filter(type='normal').\
                 extra(select={'total':'width*height'}).\
                 values('id', 'total').\
                 annotate(amount=Sum('total'))
```

but it does not work, the error I get is that TOTAL is not in the model. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what you can do:

```
Triangle.objects.filter(type="normal").values('color').annotate(amount=Sum('id', field="width * height")
```

This will produce the following query (I've simplified for readability):

```
SELECT color, sum(width * height) as amount
FROM triangle 
WHERE type = 'normal'
GROUP BY color
```

Note: I've assumed `color` is a field of `Triangle` model as other fields.

Comment: Is this an undocumented feature...? I don't see it anywhere on the Django docs Aggregation page. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @tufelkinder it's being a while I've used django and the answer was posted long ago. After a quick look at the docs, I don't see that `field` keyword documented. Good catch, would be glad if you can find a documentation reference. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use this on Django 1.11, but the `field` parameter did not calculate as the example, the `amount` just filled by the value of `id` column.