# annotate group by in django

Tags: django, group-by, django-annotate

I'm trying to perform a query in django that is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity * price) from Sales GROUP BY date.
```

My django query looks like this:

```
Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sum=Sum('price * quantity'))
```

The above one throws error:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'price * quantity' into field

Then I came up with another query after checking this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18220269/12113049

```
Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sum=Sum('price', field='price*quantity'))
```

Unfortunately, this is not helping me much. It gives me `SUM(price) GROUP BY date` instead of `SUM(quantity*price) GROUP BY date`.

How do I query this in django?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [`F` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to perform operations on fields:

```
from django.db.models import F

Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sum=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity')))
```

**Edit**: assuming that `price` is a `DecimalField` and `quantity` is a `IntegerField` (of different types) you would need to specify `output_field` in `Sum`:

```
from django.db.models import DecimalField, F

Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sum=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity'), output_field=DecimalField()))
```

Comment: In my case I have to add output_field: Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(total_sum=Sum(F('price')*F('quantity'),  output_field=FloatField())). This returns empty query set.

Comment: @MaruthiEranki didn't think what your field types were, edited.

Comment: Sorry for that. I made output_field as FloatField. Issue now is that, django query is not returning any query set. Though I have data.

Comment: @MaruthiEranki Are you sure you are using the proper variable, etc.? Or using the proper database? Try directly printing the queryset: `print(Sales.objects.values('date').annotate(.....))`

Comment: Yes, if I do Sum(F('price')), then it is returning set. Only when I multiply F('price') * F('quantity') it is returning empty set. Don't know what exactly the issue is.